# no data ingested in the output table after using dolphindb subscribeTable

Tags: streaming, subscription, dolphindb

The DolphinDB `subscribeTable` uses the handler to filter and insert data into the output table, but there is no data in the output table.

```
share streamTable(1000:0, `time`a, [TIMESTAMP, DOUBLE]) as table1
share streamTable(1000:0, `time`a, [TIMESTAMP, DOUBLE]) as table2
def append_after_filtering(inputTable, msg){
t = select * from msg where a>100
insert into inputTable values(t.time,t.a)
}
subscribeTable(tableName="table1", actionName="test", offset=-1, handler=append_after_filtering{table2}, msgAsTable=true)
```

I have subscribed to table1 and want to filter the message and save it to table2, but there is no data in table2.

Answer (score 0):

When defining the handler, the inputTable needs to be modified with the keyword mutable to indicate variable parameter.

```
share streamTable(1000:0, `time`a, [TIMESTAMP, DOUBLE]) as table1
share streamTable(1000:0, `time`a, [TIMESTAMP, DOUBLE]) as table2
def append_after_filtering(mutable inputTable, msg){
t = select * from msg where a>100
insert into inputTable values(t.time,t.a)
}
subscribeTable(tableName="table1", actionName="test", offset=-1, handler=append_after_filtering{table2}, msgAsTable=true)
```